# Apache SOLR 5.5 hangs during indexing

Tags: java, solr, sitecore

I am trying to setup SOLR for Sitecore with pretty big content tree (~300k items, ~25 GB Database size).
When I try to rebuild biggest indexes (like sitecore_web_index and sitecore_master_index) my SOLR instance goes down with error:

```
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst><lst name="initFailures"/><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException</str></lst><str name="msg">Error handling 'status' action </str><str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error handling 'status' action 
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation$4.call(CoreAdminOperation.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:354)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:155)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:676)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:439)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/solr/data/sitecore_master_index/data/index/segments_90
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
    at java.nio.file.Files.size(Files.java:2332)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:210)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.fileLength(NRTCachingDirectory.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler.getIndexInfo(LukeRequestHandler.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.getCoreStatus(CoreAdminOperation.java:886)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation$4.call(CoreAdminOperation.java:188)
    ... 27 more
```

VM for SOLR have 8 Gb RAM, enough HDD space, 4 vCPU's assigned.
Java options is -Xms1024m -Xmx7168m

I shall note, that this failure is permament, and SOLR will not come back alive until it will be restarted manually.

Comment: I know this may happen when your `schema.xml` file is out of date (from some old Solr version). Have you used Sitecore `schema.xml` file generator? Can you compare your schema file with the original schema for that Solr version?

Comment: Yes, I used Sitecore schema generator. But, Sitecore itself is pushing us to use old schema format: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897
In SOLR 5.5 default schema.xml there is no <field> and <types> tag

Comment: And if you try to clear the `sitecore_web_index` and force republish parts of the tree - instead of doing full republish? Would you be able to find maybe an item which is causing troubles?

Comment: Hmmm.. interesting idea. But is it an item which possibly make SOLR stop?